# What is wrong with my code

Tags: c

I have to write a program in c language and this is the code : The problem is that when I try to compile it it says : syntax error before return .Where is my error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{ 
  char i,c2,j;
  int c=4;
  i=j=3;
  while (++i <=c)
  {
    int j=1;
    printf("\n Nr1=%c Nr2=%d",64+i,c2);
  } do;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: "What is wrong with my code ?" - ***formatting.***

Comment: Your `do..while` is backwards.

Comment: it's either 'do { } while'  OR 'while { }'

Comment: This code is an error.

Comment: Also, consult a beginner C language tutorial. Stack Overflow isn't there for teachning you a language.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `do` from your code. Just `while (++i <= c) { /* ... */ };`

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring `j` inside the while loop. Remove `int j=1;`

and remove the `do;` at the end of your `while`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `while ...  do` loop in C. There are `while` loops or `do ... while` loops.